# As a Canadian citizen living as a legal resident in the United States, with no income: do I need to file in Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, income-tax, non-resident

I am a Canadian citizen but I married an American and live as a legal resident in the US.  My husband supports us and I did not bring in any taxable income in 2012.  Do I need to file a Canadian return?  If I make money in 2013, will I need to file in Canada at that point?

Comment: The answer may depend on other factors not disclosed.  When did you leave Canada?  Do you maintain any ties to Canada, e.g. drivers' license, health card, property, investments of any kind?

Comment: OP here.  I left Canada in January of 2012.  I have a Canadian passport, but no health card, driver's license, property, or investments.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [non Residency status in Canada](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/nnrsdnts/ndvdls/nnrs-eng.html) you don't need to file Canadian tax return. To confirm your status you need to contact Canada Revenue (send them letter, probably to complete some form).