# Is it true that as long as you are on a TN visa you have to file taxes in Canada as residents?

Tags: income-tax, canada, tn-visa

My husband has been working in the USA on a TN visa since August 2012. Me and my son moved to USA in August 2014. My husband has been filing taxes in the US as a non-resident and in Canada as a resident. His TN visa is valid for another 2.5 years. But now we all moved here and we don't have a house in Canada. We only have bank accounts, credit cards and OHIP cards. For the year 2014 do we have to file in Canada as residents?

Is it true that as long as you are on a TN visa you have to file taxes in Canada as residents? My husband is saying that if he didn't file in Canada his future TN visa renewal may be in jeopardy. Is that true?

Comment: He should be filing as a resident alien for US taxes. The US tax page [here](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Taxation-by-VISA-Type---Taxation-of-Nonimmigrants-in-TN-Status) and a page on calculating residency (or not) in Canada [here](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/nnrsdnts/ndvdls/nnrs-eng.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But we still have canadian bank account and credit cards. Does that mean we have residential ties with canada and we have to file caandian taxes as resident?

Comment: please see my answer to similar question: http://money.stackexchange.com/a/21752/6721

, not sure about Canadian bank account and credit card. Maybe you should contact Revenue and ask them.